# How to implement a BorderLayout in HTML/CSS using flexbox properly?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, border-layout

Please find here a HTML snippet and the corresponding CSS which build a BorderLayout:

https://jsbin.com/zokutalafe/edit?html,css,output

```
-
```

The yellow area in that BorderLayout example shall have a height of 100%, unfortunatelly it has not :-(

The question is now: Is it possible to change that yellow container's height to 100% by just modifying the CSS, NOT(!) the HTML, without using new [Edit: I mean "additional"] CSS selectors (means: something like ".borderlayout-center > div { height:  100% }" is not allowed)???

This is for a very special use case - that's why I have the above mentioned strange constraints.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:

```
.borderlayout-center div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: [Same comment as above]: Sorry for being ambigous: "without new CSS selectors" => I meant "without aditional CSS selectors" ... the use case is that it's for a certain React component where I am only allowed to use inline styles and ".boderlayout-center div" cannot be simulated just by styles.

Comment: add a inline style to `<div style="background-color: yellow;">` this div

Comment: Thanks ... of course this will do the job, but in my special use case that will have some subtile side effects - I would like to avoid this. Nevertheless this will be my workaround if it's not working otherwise.

Comment: What did you mean by subtile side effects?

Comment: That <div style="background-color: yellow">...</div> element will actually be in React <div className={{props.className}} style={{props.style}}>...</div>. If props.style is given then I have to use: const newProps = Object.assign({}, props.style, { height: '100%' }) which is surely a solution, but maybe not a very nice solution and I'am wondering whether there's a better solution - that's why I've asked

Comment: Of course it's: <div className={props.className} style={props.style}>...</div> .... I've accidently used "{{" and "}}" above

Comment: Sorry i don't have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure what you mean with new CSS selectors

But something like

```
.borderlayout-center div{
  height: 100%;
}
```

it's nothing new and it works...

Comment: Sorry for being ambigous: "without new CSS selectors" => I meant "without aditional CSS selectors" ... the use case is that it's for a certain React component where I am only allowed to use inline styles and ".boderlayout-center div" cannot be simulated just by styles.

Comment: as far as i know and as much as i can think of, ther's no solution if this is your situation. If you cannot add any class to the inner div or if you cannot use any other "selector", i cannot even start to think at a workaround